# Why is this condition false?

Tags: php, string, floating-point, comparison

Some strange things are going on in my code. Could someone explain please why is this condition false?

When I output object's members with php's function `var_dump()`, I get this:

```
string(6) "105.63"
float(105.63)
```

from one object, and this is output from another object:

```
string(6) "667.69"
float(667.69)
```

Then I do comparison like this:

```
if(105.63 == "105.63"){
    echo "true";    
} else {
    echo "false";
}
if(667.69 == "667.69"){
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

it outputs 2 times `true` for sure, if we write code like in my example above. But in my class, it behaves differently. In first `if` I get `false` and in second `if` I get `true`. Then I looked to the data more deeply with `var_export()` function and it seems like I actually have following data:

```
'105.63'
105.6300000000000096633812063373625278472900390625
```

and

```
'667.69'
667.69000000000005456968210637569427490234375
```

So I decide to check wether my conditions work with that data... And they dont. Actually, only first one doesn't. Why do I get output `false` and `true` in following code?

```
if(105.6300000000000096633812063373625278472900390625 == "105.63"){
    echo "true";    
} else {
    echo "false";
}
if(667.69000000000005456968210637569427490234375 == "667.69"){
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
```

I know how to fix this. But I'm interested why conditions fails in first `if`.

**EDIT**

Php does type juggling when we use `==` comparison operator!
Take a look at this:

```
var_export((float) "105.63");
var_export((string) 105.6300000000000096633812063373625278472900390625);
var_export((float) "667.69");
var_export((string) 667.69000000000005456968210637569427490234375);
```

outputs:

```
105.63
'105.63'
667.69000000000005
'667.69'
```

Should not this mean that the first condition be true and the second false? But I get false in first and true in second. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: [Floating point representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)

Comment: For the same reason you can't represent the ratio 1/3 in a decimal system using a finite amount of paper, binary has the same problem. Don't use `==` for floats, instead use `abs($number-$otherNumber) < $epsilon` where `$epsilon` is an arbitrarily small constant (precision).

Comment: check my edit please.

Answer (score 3):

Check the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

There is a big warning section about comparing floating point numbers:

**WARNING**

> Floating point precision
>
> Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on
>   the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format,
>   which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order
>   of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger
>   errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered when
>   several operations are compounded. Additionally, rational numbers that
>   are exactly representable as floating point numbers in base 10, like
>   0.1 or 0.7, do not have an exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is used internally, no matter the size of the
>   mantissa. Hence, they cannot be converted into their internal binary
>   counterparts without a small loss of precision. This can lead to
>   confusing results: for example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually
>   return 7 instead of the expected 8, since the internal representation
>   will be something like 7.9999999999999991118.... So never trust
>   floating number results to the last digit, and do not compare floating
>   point numbers directly for equality. If higher precision is necessary,
>   the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp functions are
>   available. For a "simple" explanation, see the » floating point guide
>   that's also titled "Why don’t my numbers add up?"

[Why dont my numbers add up?](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: check my edit please.